# dataframe to json file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert dataframe to json file. Currently my dataframe looks like this:

```
a           b 
P1          7950
P2          1274
P3          6160
```

I want to conver this dataframe into json file in which values from first column would be keys and from second column would be values: so like `{P1:7950, P2:1274, P3:6160)`

I tried this but it produces output in incorrect form (not the want I stated above)

```
df.set_index('a').to_json()
```

Comment: Isn't there a `to_dict` method you can use for DFs? Then just write that to a json file.

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.to_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: I tried this already and it doesnt produce output i want

Comment: Or you just skip and go straight to JSON... didn't know that was a thing. I'm consistently impressed with pandas

Comment: you should display your attempt in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create `Series` with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`Series.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
j = df.set_index('a')['b'].to_json()
print (j)
{"P1":7950,"P2":1274,"P3":6160}
```

For file:

```
df.set_index('a')['b'].to_json(filename)
```

Answer (score -3):

There's a df.to_json() method available

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

The examples in the documentation show the different formats you may wish to output the json object in.

Comment: I know this method but i was figuring out how to achieve the output format I needed as all different orients will result in different formats